# Capturing click event for dynamically created command buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has multiple adjustable headers based on a list for another sheet. I need to do the adjustments without using data validation due to other code in the workbook. I created a userform with dynamically generated command button to grab the list from the formatting sheet, create a command button for each entry in the list and format/space them into the userform. Then when a command button is selected from the userform to close the form and change the active header cell from the reports sheet to the command button caption. Each column also has a on change event to update all data in that column based on the new header.

My issue is that the code work fine until it gets to where it calls the Class1 module to create the command button click event. It skips this part of the code without any error or hesitation and just doesn't do it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B2:ZZ2")) Is Nothing Then
        HeadersForm.Show
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataColumn As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CommandButton As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim totalCommandButtons As Integer
    Dim CommandButtonsPerColumn As Integer
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim numColumns As Integer
    Dim buttonWidth As Integer
    Dim buttonHeight As Integer
    Dim leftMargin As Integer
    Dim topMargin As Integer
    Dim rowSpacing As Integer
    Dim colSpacing As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting")

    i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataColumn = ws.Range("A2:A" & i)

    totalCommandButtons = dataColumn.Cells.Count
    CommandButtonsPerColumn = 4

    numRows = (totalCommandButtons + CommandButtonsPerColumn - 1) \ CommandButtonsPerColumn
    numColumns = Application.Min(CommandButtonsPerColumn, totalCommandButtons)

    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)
    
    
    buttonWidth = 100
    buttonHeight = 20
    leftMargin = 10
    topMargin = 10
    rowSpacing = 5
    colSpacing = 5

    Me.Width = leftMargin + numColumns * (buttonWidth + colSpacing) - colSpacing + 2 * leftMargin
    Me.Height = topMargin + numRows * (buttonHeight + rowSpacing) - rowSpacing + 2 * topMargin + 15

    For Each cell In dataColumn.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            Set CommandButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CommandButton_" & cell.Row - 1)
            CommandButton.Caption = cell.Value
            CommandButton.Width = buttonWidth
            CommandButton.Height = buttonHeight

            With CommandButton
                .Left = leftMargin + ((cell.Row - 2) Mod CommandButtonsPerColumn) * (buttonWidth + colSpacing)
                .Top = topMargin + ((cell.Row - 2) \ CommandButtonsPerColumn) * (buttonHeight + rowSpacing)
            End With

            SetCommandClickEvent CommandButton
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub SetCommandClickEvent(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)

    Set CommandButtonEventHandler = New Class1
    Set CommandButtonEventHandler.CommandButton = btn
    
End Sub
```

Then in a class module

```
Public WithEvents CommandButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

    If CommandButton.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = CommandButton.Caption
    End If
    
        HeadersForm.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: `CommandButtonEventHandler` goes out of scope as soon as  `SetCommandClickEvent` exits....

Comment: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73510523/11318818) including the 'edit' for adding multiple CommandButtons ... this code includes an array at the UserForm level to hold the CommandButtons (to keep them in-scope per @TimWilliams comment)

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams this worked like a charm. I did have to make one minor change to my code, in the click event: If CommandButton.Value = True Then, I had to change it to: If CommandButton.Value = False Then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CommandButtonEventHandler` object goes out of scope as soon as `SetCommandClickEvent` exits.

You need somewhere to store your class instances - a `Collection` is a good place.

```
Dim ColEvents as Collection 'needs to be global to stay in scope

Private Sub SetCommandClickEvent(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    If ColEvents Is Nothing Then Set ColEvents = New Collection
    Set CommandButtonEventHandler = New Class1
    Set CommandButtonEventHandler.CommandButton = btn
    ColEvents.Add CommandButtonEventHandler 
End Sub
```